# Glyth icons are not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Glyth icons are not displaying at all in firefox 12 and 13 (windows) using rails-admin 0.0.3 and bootstrap-sass 2.0.3, is that a known issue?

Comment: What do you see in browser's console (Firebug in this case)? Any errors? Any problems with styles? Anything you have found so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glyth icons are included in bootstrap-sass https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/vendor/assets/images

If it works in any other web browser clear firefox cache.

If it's not working in any web browser use firebug to see which path is expected

[image: twitter boostrap glyth icons firebug]